# The prefix "mvc" for element "mvc:annotation-driven" is not bound : Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Getting

> HTTP Status 500 - Servlet.init() for servlet mvc-dispatcher threw
>   exception.

Exception:

> javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet
>   mvc-dispatcher threw exception.

Root Cause:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException:
>   Line 8 in XML document from ServletContext resource
>   [/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml] is invalid; nested exception is
>   org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 8; columnNumber: 29; The
>   prefix "mvc" for element "mvc:annotation-driven" is not bound.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml file.

Look for beans xmlns at the top.

Add

> xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"

in the

```
<beans xmlns ....>
```

tag start.